# Code optimization for Opencv Android

Tags: android, c++, optimization, image-processing, opencv

I'm using this opencv code on Android for an intensity equalization. The time of execution is around 300ms per frame (720x480). Does anybody have an idea for a possible time optimization ?

Here is the code :

```
        cvtColor(image, hsvImage, CV_BGR2HSV);
        // Get intensity
        intensity = hsvImage.at<Vec3b>((int)reference.Point_::y, (int)reference.Point_::x);
        float value = (float)REGULAR_INTENSITY / intensity[2];
        float saturation = (float)REGULAR_SATURATION / intensity[1];
        if (counter == 15 && (int)intensity[2] < REGULAR_INTENSITY) {
            equalization = false;
        }
        // Modify intensity
        float transformedSaturation, transformedValue;
        for(int i = 0; i < hsvImage.rows; i++) {
            unsigned char *data = hsvImage.ptr(i);
            for(int j = 0; j < hsvImage.cols; j++) {
                transformedSaturation = (uchar)*++data * saturation;
                if (transformedSaturation > MAX_COLOR) {
                    transformedSaturation = MAX_COLOR;
                }
                *data++ = transformedSaturation;
                transformedValue = (uchar)*data * value;
                if (transformedValue > MAX_COLOR) {
                    transformedValue = MAX_COLOR;
                }
                *data++ = transformedValue;
            }
        }
        cvtColor(hsvImage, image, CV_HSV2BGR);
```

Comment: have you found out which piece of code consumes most of the time? How much time spent on cvtColor and on the main loop?

Comment: The last line : CV_HSV2BGR conversion. I think nothing can be done.

Comment: Consider using gpu::cvtColor for color conversion, if applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using OpenCV [transform](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=transform#cv.Transform) ? I guess it is optimised, but I dont know about the saturating cast (that is if > max_color, then = max color)

Comment: Thanks but as you see i'm multiplying with an array which depends on the src array, it is not static.

Comment: As I see you compute a multiplier for Intensity, Value, Saturation and you use these values to equalize the full data. So you just need to create a 1x3 matrix, fill it with intensity, saturation, value and call cv::transform!